# How to detect url callback request

Tags: python, network-programming

I have a locally-run app that makes API calls to a website ([`tumblr.com`](https://tumblr.com)). This involves setting some OAuth credentials; one step along the way requires extracting a key from a callback url that the server directs the browser to. So what I currently have the user do is:

1. Open an authorization link in a browser, which prompts them to authorize the OAuth application on the website
2. Click through the authorization page on the website (“*Yes, I allow xxxxx app to access certain info associated with my account*”)
3. Clicking `Authorize app` makes a request to the localhost which includes a parameter in the url. Meaning that tumblr will redirect the browser to the page `http://localhost/?oauth_token={TOKEN}&oauth_verifier={VERIFIER}#_=_`. I assume that causes a request to be made to the local machine when it does that.
4. The user is expected to isolate the key parameter in the url from the browser’s navigation bar, and paste it in the application.

So is there any way I can bypass steps 3 and 4 and simply have the app pick up the callback request instead of expecting the user to copy and paste it from the browser? I’m afraid I don’t know much about how to handle network requests in python.

To be clear, what I need to do is get the `{VERIFIER}` string.

Comment: Hey, do you mind detailing point 3?

Comment: @Loïc i clarified point 3. The callback url is really a tumblr redirect except instead of making a request to another server, it’s supposed to make a request to the local computer since the script is locally run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay first thing first, for http requests, a good python module is `requests`

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Then, your app gives a callback address to tumblr so that tumblr can tell to your app client info, or login error.

Now, your point 3 isn't clear.
"Clicking authorize app makes a request to localhost"

Actually clicking "authorize app" for the user makes a request to tumblr saying he accepts.
Then tumblr makes a request to your callback url passing the infos.

The callback url should probably be your server address, there you must have a script listening for tumblr, which will give you your special parameter to call their api...

**In addition :**

So when the users click "authorize app" there is a request to tumblr, which redirects the user to the callback url (adding oauth token and verifier).

Now, obviously, you can't ask for every user to have an http server running on their computer.

So you must set the callback url to your server.

So if you set it to "myserver.com/tumblr" for instance, the user will get redirected to your webpage, and you'll get on your server, and for that user session, the oauths token and verifier.

**and...**

Assuming your app is client only I'd say there are two options.

Either have your users enter manually their API keys.

Or either embed a webserver into your app.

In the case of the embedded webserver, I'd suggest flask for its simplicity.
Simply have your webserver listen on a given port and set the callback url to that server:port.

This way you'll get the client tokens directly.

Comment: there is no second server, all the listening is supposed to occur on the local computer

Comment: Answer edited, but please tell me, don't you have a web server?

Comment: no, because the app is really more of a toolkit, it’s not supposed to rely on a third party

Comment: You don't have a local web server? You need a webserver to be called by tumblr to give you the access code (to exchange for a token).  Otherwise you shouldn't be using OAuth. If you're just trying to access your own data/public data you may be able to without OAuth from a quick glance at their API docs. Just register an application to get an API Key, then you can make requests to the endpoints that don't require authentication. If you want to access an endpoint that requires authentication (meaning you are accessing someone else's data) you need to do OAuth to get access from that user.

Comment: so you have to get the redirect request from tumblr within your app.
I'd suggest setting callback url to localhost:8080 (for instance) and within your app, embed a webserver (I'd go for flask) to get these tokens.

Comment: @Loïc i think that sounds like what I need. How would I do that?

Comment: @GeneralKandalaft the application is a toolkit that lets the user manage their own tumblr account (which requires user credentials). I initially built it for my own use but I want to let others use the code & the toolkit without me having to set up a web server to support them

Comment: Just embed a webserver into your app. Like run flask, make it listen on an uncommon port, and set the callback url to localhost.

Comment: Then you may want to make this behave like most SDKs and have a parameter for the user to put in their own API key to make a request with. If you don't want the user to have to put in their own API key when using the toolkit then do what @loïc suggested.

Comment: @Loïc probably a dumb question but which ports are uncommon?

Comment: I often use 8080 8081 and the like for "uncommon" http port.
but check this list : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Comment: @Loïc okay thank you that was exactly what i need! if you mind editing your answer with that i will accept